# Are too many if , else-if statements wrong?

Tags: java

I have to do a program that's simulating the move of an ant in a 5x5 grid map,of cells. Imagine an 5x5 array in which, in position (2,2) and (3,3) there is food for ants to collect. Every ant starts moving from its nest which is in a specific cell (1,4 or 4,1). There is a method called move() that i have to write,which moves the ant one cell in each call. The move can either be horizontal or vertical. Also the ant cant move to his last position (to avoid going back and forth). Also each cell has 'smell points' and the ant prefers to go in the cell with the biggest points(so you compare its available options and pick the one with the biggest smell points,simple right?). Now, the problem. They want the ant to make completely random moves incase the cell has no smell points or the smell points of the available cells are equal. So to sum it up:

1. if statement to check in which cell the ant is. When you find it you know where to look for his previous move.
2. nested if statement to check in which cell the ant was last. That's 3 or 4 if statements in a 5x5 area. When you find the last,in which the ant can't move,you know which cells to compare .
3. nested if statement between 2 or 3 cells to find the one with the most smell points.
4. nested if statement in case their smell points are equal or 0. In this case the ant moves completely random( i made it via Math.random() ).
   All the above is for just one cell!. Each cell has different options because of its location in map.
   So to make this as you can see i need way too many if statements. I can't even count them without getting mind blowned! But i can't imagine a way to make this without if statements. Also every cell its different and the ant has different options to move , so I can't categorise it . For example , imagine the ant is in (1,1) . It can go to (1,2) or (2,1) only . If it is at (4,2) it can go to (4,3)or(3,2)or(4,1)or(5,2)! You have to make 4 if statement to check which one of these was his last position and then go on with the other nested ifs...
   So what do you think?
   Is it wrong to have so many ifs?

```
// int pos[] = new int[2]; in the pos[0] is the position for the x, pos[1] for the y.
if(isAt(1,1))
        {
          if(wasAt(pos[0]+1,pos[1]))
          {
            previousX = pos[0];
            previousY = pos[1];
            pos[1] = pos[1] + 1;
          }
          else
          {
            previousX = pos[0];
            previousY = pos[1];
            pos[0] = pos[0] + 1;
          }
        }
```

Comment: Is it hard to keep track of what the code is doing? If so, it's too complicated.

Comment: Yeah it is! To be honest im forced to do it this way, without extra functions to help me keep track of everything! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does sound like too many `if` statements.  Here are some suggestions:

1. You should remember where the ant is in a variable.  I don't think you need any if statements to check which cell the ant is in.
2. You should remember where the ant was last in a different variable.
3. You should make a list of the surrounding points and their smell points.  Then remove from this list the ants previous location.
4. Using the above collection, you can loop through to pick the right one or if there is more than one choose one at random from the collection.

When you move the ant, set the previous location to the current location and then update the current location.

Comment: I have functions and variables that store the information you are saying. I will try to write some of the code above

Comment: I have put code in my questin.Check it out

Comment: Also this is a code that comes complete and i have to make only some functions .Its an excersice from university, i cant make it my own, sadly